# Sleeping NSThread Vs. GCD dispatch after

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Maybe this question has been asked before in a different form. But I think I am looking at this differently. I am doing some optimisation task for the entire codebase and lots of refactoring and that would server the readability of the code also.

So I found `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` method written somewhere and for the delays I always use the GCD's `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(<#delayInSeconds#> * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{})` method. So the question is which is better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a huge difference.

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]
```

blocks the current thread. This is terrible if the current thread is the main thread. And it may be fine or terrible on other threads depending on what you are doing.

```
dispatch_after
```

doesn't block the current thread. The block is queued up to run at a future time on the designated queue while the current thread continues on its merry way.

Without any specific context, I would say that `dispatch_after` is the much better approach in almost all cases.

Comment: Well, that I do understand but what if it's a background thread that only adds something to a queue? And another thing and it may sound stupid, performance wise, will it matter?

Comment: If you have a specific use-case you are concerned about, perhaps you should update your question with specific details. But it will be the rare case that `sleepForTimeInterval` is the better solution.

Comment: No sadly I don't have a use case for it and I strongly agrees with you. But hypothetically speaking if both it was on a background thread, will it matter after all?

Comment: Absolutely. Again, `sleepForTimeInterval` blocks the current thread while `dispatch_after` doesn't. You may want the thread to keep doing other work. But it can't if you use `sleepForTimeInterval`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer if you fell it is appropriate.

Comment: You only have a limited number of threads. One sleepForTimeInterval, if it's not on the main thread, doesn't hurt much (it hurts, just not much). Many will hurt. dispatch_after just adds the code block to a queue and is done. Absolutely minimal cost.

Comment: @rmaddy I did upvote your answer but I'm just giving a bit of time for people to give more solutions. But as I said, your answer is great! :)

Comment: If you are sleeping for a time interval on the global, low priority queue... that should be fine? Empirically it's fine on all iOS devices, but I'm wondering if I'm missing anything or perhaps hurting performance with this stupidity...? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When considering replacing uses of `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` with GCD's `dispatch_after`, there are a couple of things to consider. As @rmaddy said, `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` blocks the thread on which it's called. As pointed out, this would be very bad for the main thread, and more generally any thread with a run loop on it (because the run loop will not iterate during that call.)

If you have a thread with a run loop on it, you can "spin" the runloop for some amount of time, which allows other run loop sources to remain responsive while the calling thread of execution remains effectively blocked. Details of spinning a run loop are beyond the scope of the question, but using run loops is yet another way you could solve this problem (although GCD is probably still preferred if you're not pushed into using run loops by some other API that relies on them like, for instance, `NSStream`.)

The primary high-level reason to avoid blocking threads with `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` is that threads are a finite resource. If you were to make a loop spawning many threads, all of which subsequently became blocked by virtue of calling `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]`, you would eventually be unable to create more threads. Thread exhaustion isn't a problem with particularly elegant solutions in the framework, because in general, it's a situation that the framework expects you to avoid, at an architectural level, by using a better abstraction like GCD or run loops.

One other situation where `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` will differ substantially from `dispatch_after` is when there is thread-local storage in play.  If your code has done something like `[[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary][@"foo"] = @"bar";` then after `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` returns, you will be on the exact same thread, and therefore the value you had put into thread-local storage will still be there. With `dispatch_after` there is no guarantee that your block will run on the same thread from which it was enqueued. (And the overall likelihood of that happening by chance is fairly low as well in a process with other background tasks in flight.) In general, it's not a great idea to use TLS with GCD. That's generally OK because the ability to capture variables in block closures can solve many of the problems that people have historically used TLS to solve.

Thread-local storage is one of those things that can be extremely useful when it solves a given problem, but can make code brittle in the face of refactorings like this. What's worse is that you might not be able to know that other parts of the code are relying on TLS except by seeing things fail (or act weird).

Long story short, there's not enough info here to say which mechanism is best for your situation. If one were starting from scratch though, I struggle to think of a reason one would choose to block a thread using `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` instead of using a more modern deferral mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a million! This is so informative and well detailed. :)